# Global sections of symmetric product of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a irreducible, smooth, projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $L$ be a globally generated line bundle over $C$.  Let $h^0(C,L)=m.$

Consider the product $C \times C$. If $p_i:C \times C \rightarrow C$ for $i=1,2$ are the projections, then $p_1^*L\otimes p_2^*L$ is a globally generated line bundle on $C \times C$. Also by Kunneth formula, $H^0(C \times C,  p_1^*L\otimes p_2^*L)=H^0(C,L) \otimes  H^0(C,L)$. Hence $h^0(C \times C,  p_1^*L\otimes p_2^*L)= m^2$.

1) I want to know what sections descend to $S^2C$, the quotient of $C\times C$ by the action of the symmetric group $S^2$. These are the sections which are invariant under the involution $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$. How to find this out.

2) Since $L$ is a line bundle over $C$. $L$ has the form $L=\mathcal{O}_C(D)$, where $D=\Sigma a_i$ for $i=1,....,d$. Then $p_1^*L\otimes p_2^*L=O_{C\times C}(D \times C + C \times D)$. Hence if we consider the line bundle corresponding to the divisor $D+C=  \Sigma a_i+C$ on $S^2C$, then it pulls back to $p_1^*L\otimes p_2^*L$  right? Can we find the dimension of global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{S^2C}(D+C)$ in terms of m?

So basically I want to find out which sections descend to the symmetric product. How to approach this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is D+C a divisor on S2C ?

Comment: The invariant sections are clearly $S^2V\subset V\otimes V$ where $V=H^0(C,L)$.

Comment: @mercio, If $x\in C$, the image of $\{x\}\times C$ in $S^2C$ is a divisor right? Is this not a sum of such divisors?